# Server side react-apollo wp graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, acfpro

I'm using ReactJS server side rendering with express and react-apollo.

Everything working perfectly until I use WP acf PRO.
GraphiQL show these fields, also if I console.log it in reactjs component it shows these values in node server only not in client side. But If I remove ACF pro fields then react-apollo get everything in cient side also.

Query I use:

```
const TEST_DATA = gql`
  query test {
    page(id: "/homepage", idType: URI, asPreview: false) {
      homePageCustom {
        homePage {
          __typename
          ... on Page_Homepagecustom_HomePage_SomeData {
            enabled
            fieldGroupName
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Component I use:

```
const FrontPage = (props) => {
  const { loading, error,  data } = useQuery(TEST_DATA, {
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
    errorPolicy: "all",
    variables: {},
    onError: (d) => {
      console.log(d);
    },
    onCompleted: (d) => {
      console.log("onComplete", d);
    },
  });

  if (loading) return <div>...Loading</div>;
  if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

  console.log("data", data, error, loading);

  return (
    <div>
     Some data here
    </div>
  );
};

export default FrontPage;
```

If I use that query then client side show data and working:

```
const TEST_DATA = gql`
      query test {
        page(id: "/homepage", idType: URI, asPreview: false) {
          homePageCustom {
            homePage {
              __typename
              ... on Page_Homepagecustom_HomePage_SomeData {
                __typename
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `;
```

My client side settings:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: createHttpLink({ uri: webConfig.siteURLGraphQL }),
  cache: cache.restore(window.__APOLLO_STATE__),
});

const SSRApp = (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <CookiesProvider>
        <App />
      </CookiesProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </ApolloProvider>
);

ReactDOM.hydrate(SSRApp, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

Its interesting that window._ *APOLLO_STATE* _ get these values I need.
Maybe there are some settings error in my react-apollo setup?

Im really confused and tried 3 days and nothing seems working.

Comment: security ... some data/fields are not publicly available - server/graphiql playground works with admin rights

Comment: Yes, thats right, but I get that query in server side(node), there are everything okei and working. But client side has undefined data.

Comment: Don't you think it should work client side before making SSR?

Comment: It's working fine in client-side. I have multiple other queries that are also working fine. Only problem is when I add enabled and fieldGroupName values. I have tried change wp custom acf fields names and refreshed values and so on... I dont understand why it only breaks with these values. It seems like react-apollo has some problem with these fragment/union fields. Or I need some extra settings for my SSR. I have followed react apollo introductions to setup it

Comment: not a client problem ... SSRed can have this data but after hydrating it should work as usual runtime client  ... again ... make these fields running/available in any client, f.e. use postman

Comment: Tested with postman, everything working, got data. It seems to be some react-apollo problem/bug...?. Because I figured out that it works only if each ACF flexible Content layout has same values. If there are some different values then automatically error

Comment: hmm.... id? ... cache requires unique ids (`id`, `_id` or other configured) per each type ... to be cached properly

Comment: Nope, nothing working. Tried multiple different fields (text, true/false etc..) nothing. I dont know is it problem that only occurs in my project or there are someone who has/had same problem. At the moment the solution is that I add same values for all fields and thats it. It is not best solution but nothing else working.

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#generating-unique-identifiers ... network response (show?) can have data but it's saved in cache before view update, without id/unique key data is not saved/not delivered to hook

Comment: I'm not 100 percent sure how it is correct to setup in my case. But these settings I tried did not work.